# Using CuPy on Maxwell GPU

Tags: cupy

Anyone here trying to use cupy on a Maxwell GPU? I am trying to do a simple `array.mean()` operation and getting the message below. Is there a way I can get around this? Do I need to install a different cuda version? Different cupy version? Or do I need to resign to buying a new gpu?

```
---------------------------------------------------
--- JIT compile log for cupy_jitify_exercise ---
---------------------------------------------------
cub/util_cpp_dialect.cuh(143): warning #161-D: unrecognized #pragma
       CUB_COMPILER_DEPRECATION_SOFT(C++14, C++11);
       ^

Remark: The warnings can be suppressed with "-diag-suppress <warning-number>"

std/barrier(16): catastrophic error: #error directive: "CUDA synchronization primitives are only supported for sm_70 and up."
  #  error "CUDA synchronization primitives are only supported for sm_70 and up."
     ^

1 catastrophic error detected in the compilation of "cupy_jitify_exercise".
Compilation terminated.

---------------------------------------------------
```

I am running a GTX 980 with compute_cap of 5.2. I installed cuda in ubuntu using the latest docs from nvidia. Here is the output from `nvidia-smi`

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.23.08              Driver Version: 545.23.08    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980         On  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 26%   33C    P8              13W / 180W |     57MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       979      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           47MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1384      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          4MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling latest cupy(13.0) from my conda env and installing a previous version did it for me:

In active env:
conda install -c conda-forge cupy=12.3 cuda-version=12.4

I have the following on Debian 12:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.14              Driver Version: 550.54.14      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080        On  |   00000000:1C:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   54C    P0             50W /  210W |     572MiB /   8192MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1518      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            219MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1666      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                           85MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2933      G   ...sion,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess         95MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3453      G   /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr              167MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you!! Cupy version 13.0 was very unstable for me on linux with a 1080 Ti; I'm glad I ran into this compilation error because more frequently it would work but just take _forever_ to compile (making cupy code much _much_ slower than numpy)

Comment: @user2561747 Too bad a lot of the functionality in cupyx.scipy.signal is not included in 12.3. I'll try if I can use cuSignal instead.

Comment: Also there's more info in cupy [gitter thread](https://matrix.to/#/!oEzlbyeUFtBsFeDNbk:gitter.im/$BVXYQ4MLzgLwjJIFVuRZds9224KGlfN9Aa60dqVOT1k?via=gitter.im&via=matrix.org&via=matrix.freyachat.eu)